# Please make sure that the argument ContactRepository at index [0] is available in the RootTestModule context

Tags: typescript, jestjs, nestjs

I'm trying to test a class via Nest. In this class (cf image below), the person who coded the class, create a repository via typeorm.

[image]

When I try to test the "createContact" function I get the following error : "Nest can't resolve dependencies of the ContactService (?). Please make sure that the argument ContactRepository at index [0] is available in the AuthModule context".

This is my test class :

[image]

Do you know how to make the test take this into account and therefore not get the error anymore?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to provide an implementation for the value to be injected for `@InjectRepository(Contact)`. Fortunately, Nest provides a way to get what that injection token is using `getRepositoryToken()`. With this, you can make a custom provider to provide the token and the mock that is going to be used in the actual implementation's place. The test setup would look *something* like this:

```js
beforeEach(async () => {
  const module = await Test.createTestingModule({
    providers: [
      ContactService,
      {
        provide: getRepositoryToken(Contact),
        useValue: {
          save: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(mockContact),
          find: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue([mockContact]),
        },
      },
    ],
  }).compile();
});
```

You can provide anything you want for `save` and `find`, but doing this allows you to also check what's passed to the mock, and how many times they were called (if you're watching the mocks that is).

[You can find many more examples here](https://github.com/jmcdo29/testing-nestjs)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response.

it's work but not a all.

I use this https://github.com/jmcdo29/testing-nestjs/blob/master/apps/typeorm-sample/src/cat/cat.service.spec.ts has exemple, but i have the error connectionnotfounderror : COnnection "default" was not found. when i call the "createContact" fonction

Comment: You probably have `imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature()]` used in the test, or you're importing the module that contains the service you're testing, or some sort of combination of the two. The sample you linked works fine, you can see the CI jobs run every night and have no problems

Comment: Hi, i have open à new question for that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64728017/jest-connectionnotfounderror-connection-default-was-not-found
The problem seem to be with the repository typeorm, but i do not found why

Answer (score 2):

Check if your service constructor is injecting the Contact entity, or any other that is being accused as missing:

```
   @InjectRepository(EntityName)
    private entityNameRepository: Repository<EntityName>,
```

Just replace entityName with the corresponding entity