# (Jest) ConnectionNotFoundError: Connection "default" was not found

Tags: typescript, jestjs, nestjs

I try to test a function in class who use a typeorm repository.

To write my testing class, I Use this exemple on github : https://github.com/jmcdo29/testing-nestjs/blob/master/apps/typeorm-sample/src/cat/cat.service.spec.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository, getRepositoryToken } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { Contact } from './contact.entity';
import { CreateContactDto } from './dto/createContact.dto';
import { ContactService } from './contact.service';
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';

const myContact: CreateContactDto = {email: "email@email.com", subject: "mySubject", content: "MyContent"};

describe('ContactService', () => {
    let service: ContactService;
    let repo: Repository<Contact>;

    beforeEach(async() => {
        const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
            providers: [
                ContactService,
                {
                    provide: getRepositoryToken(Contact),
                    useValue: {
                        save: jest.fn().mockRejectedValue(myContact),
                        find: jest.fn().mockRejectedValue(myContact),
                    },
                },
            ],
        }).compile();

        service = module.get<ContactService>(ContactService);
        repo = module.get<Repository<Contact>>(getRepositoryToken(Contact))

    });

    describe('createContact', () => {
        it('createContact Ok', async () => {
            const myNewContact: CreateContactDto = {email: "email@email.com", subject: "mySubject", content: "MyContent"};

            const result = await service.createContact(myNewContact);

            expect(result.email).toEqual(myNewContact.email);
        })
    })
});
```

I don't see something wrong and i try to comment "repo = module.get..." and it's change nothing.

This is the service class :

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { Contact } from './contact.entity';
import { CreateContactDto } from './dto/createContact.dto';

@Injectable()
export class ContactService {
  constructor(
  @InjectRepository(Contact)
  private contactRepository: Repository<Contact>){}

  async createContact(createContactDto: CreateContactDto) {
    const contact = new Contact();
    Object.assign(contact, createContactDto);
    return contact.save();
  }
  async getContacts() {
    return this.contactRepository.find();
  }
}
```

And this is the error :
[image]

Thanks you for your help !

Comment: include all the code that you think is required to reproduce the issue as text, not as images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it's related to `new Contact()`. In the testing example you linked, the code uses `this.repository.create()` instead of `new Entity()`. Looking at [TypeORM's BaseEntity source code](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/src/repository/BaseEntity.ts), a lot of the `static` and `instance` methods reference a `connection` object, just like `save()`. If you instead write your `createContact` like this:

```js
  async createContact(createContactDto: CreateContactDto) {
    const contact = this.contactRepository.create(createContactDto);
    await this.contactRepsitory.save(contact);
    return contact;
  }
```

you won't have any problems.

**EDIT**: Make sure to also add a mock into your test file for the `repository.create` method. Otherwise, you'll get an error about `create` not being a function.

Comment: Thanks for the help. You need to mock create fonction too